# Wordpress block template not allowing bootstrap to control responsiveness

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, wordpress-gutenberg

I am creating a Wordpress block theme.  I want to allow Wordpress styling on all of its built in blocks; however, the blocks I am creating in my theme, I want to remove Wordpress styling and allow bootstrap to fully style them.  I have included bootstrap in my theme and it is loading…

I know it is working because when I use the class `text-primary` it formats the font the blue color.

I have written a very basic jquery/JavaScript file that if my block contains a specific class, it will search and remove the Wordpress classes listed in an array within that element.  This part works perfectly.  The reason why I did this is because Wordpress automatically adds these classes in when loading the website, and the wordpress formatting overrides the bootstrap formatting when it comes to responsiveness.  When my js file removes the classes, it removes the default wordpress responsiveness.

Before you say that this will break every time wordpress updates and changes its classes, I am including this file on a parent domain and can update it for all websites implementing my custom block theme and change the array according to the Wordpress version (which I will add later once I get this fully working).

This is where the problem comes in.  I have fully removes Wordpress from styling the custom block theme; however, bootstrap is also not styling the content when it comes to responsiveness.  I was hoping someone could look at this and tell me what is preventing bootstrap from controlling how the content displays as the screen size gets larger and smaller.  It looks as if it would work perfectly and if I take the code and upload it directly to a website without Wordpress, it styles it correctly.

The columns is set up to go from a 1 column mobile design, to a 2 column design on a bigger screen, to a 4 column design on a large screen.  But its not working within Wordpress.

My JS file:

```
var WPclasses  = [
  "wp-block-group",
  "is-layout-constrained",
  "wp-block-columns",
  "is-layout-flex",
  "wp-block-column",
  "is-layout-flow",
];



$(".WP-removeDefaultClasses").removeClass(WPclasses);
```

My Wordpress content block as it appears in the code editor

```
<!-- wp:group {"className":"container WP-removeDefaultClasses","layout":{"type":"constrained"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group container WP-removeDefaultClasses"><!-- wp:columns {"className":"row WP-removeDefaultClasses"} -->
<div class="wp-block-columns row WP-removeDefaultClasses"><!-- wp:column {"className":"col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 WP-removeDefaultClasses"} -->
<div class="wp-block-column col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 WP-removeDefaultClasses"><!-- wp:heading -->
<h2 class="wp-block-heading">Heading 1</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":10,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"none","className":"img-fluid"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large img-fluid"><img src="http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-miguel-a-padrinan-255379-1024x681.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-10"/></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:paragraph {"className":"text-primary"} -->
<p class="text-primary">Paragraph 1</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph --></div>
<!-- /wp:column -->

<!-- wp:column {"className":"col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 WP-removeDefaultClasses"} -->
<div class="wp-block-column col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 WP-removeDefaultClasses"><!-- wp:heading -->
<h2 class="wp-block-heading">Heading 1</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":9,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"none","className":"img-fluid"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large img-fluid"><img src="http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-rovenimagescom-949587-1024x683.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-9"/></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph --></div>
<!-- /wp:column -->

<!-- wp:column {"className":"col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 WP-removeDefaultClasses"} -->
<div class="wp-block-column col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 WP-removeDefaultClasses"><!-- wp:heading -->
<h2 class="wp-block-heading">Heading 1</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":8,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"none","className":"img-fluid"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large img-fluid"><img src="http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-pixabay-531880-1024x640.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-8"/></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph --></div>
<!-- /wp:column -->

<!-- wp:column {"className":"col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 WP-removeDefaultClasses"} -->
<div class="wp-block-column col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 WP-removeDefaultClasses"><!-- wp:heading -->
<h2 class="wp-block-heading">Heading 1</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":7,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"none","className":"img-fluid"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large img-fluid"><img src="http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-pixabay-220067-1024x576.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-7"/></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph --></div>
<!-- /wp:column --></div>
<!-- /wp:columns --></div>
<!-- /wp:group -->
```

The code that outputs in the source of Wordpress:

```
<div class="container WP-removeDefaultClasses">
<div class="row WP-removeDefaultClasses wp-container-5">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 WP-removeDefaultClasses">
<h2 class="wp-block-heading">Heading 1</h2>



<figure class="wp-block-image size-large img-fluid"><img decoding="async" width="1024" height="681" src="http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-miguel-a-padrinan-255379-1024x681.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-10" srcset="http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-miguel-a-padrinan-255379-1024x681.jpg 1024w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-miguel-a-padrinan-255379-300x199.jpg 300w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-miguel-a-padrinan-255379-768x511.jpg 768w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-miguel-a-padrinan-255379-1536x1021.jpg 1536w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-miguel-a-padrinan-255379-2048x1362.jpg 2048w" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px"></figure>



<p class="text-primary">Paragraph 1</p>
</div>



<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 WP-removeDefaultClasses">
<h2 class="wp-block-heading">Heading 1</h2>



<figure class="wp-block-image size-large img-fluid"><img decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="1024" height="683" src="http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-rovenimagescom-949587-1024x683.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-9" srcset="http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-rovenimagescom-949587-1024x683.jpg 1024w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-rovenimagescom-949587-300x200.jpg 300w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-rovenimagescom-949587-768x512.jpg 768w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-rovenimagescom-949587-1536x1024.jpg 1536w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-rovenimagescom-949587-2048x1365.jpg 2048w" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px"></figure>



<p>Paragraph 1</p>
</div>



<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 WP-removeDefaultClasses">
<h2 class="wp-block-heading">Heading 1</h2>



<figure class="wp-block-image size-large img-fluid"><img decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="1024" height="640" src="http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-pixabay-531880-1024x640.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-8" srcset="http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-pixabay-531880-1024x640.jpg 1024w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-pixabay-531880-300x188.jpg 300w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-pixabay-531880-768x480.jpg 768w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-pixabay-531880-1536x960.jpg 1536w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-pixabay-531880.jpg 1920w" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px"></figure>



<p>Paragraph 1</p>
</div>



<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 WP-removeDefaultClasses">
<h2 class="wp-block-heading">Heading 1</h2>



<figure class="wp-block-image size-large img-fluid"><img decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="1024" height="576" src="http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-pixabay-220067-1024x576.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-7" srcset="http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-pixabay-220067-1024x576.jpg 1024w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-pixabay-220067-300x169.jpg 300w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-pixabay-220067-768x432.jpg 768w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-pixabay-220067-1536x864.jpg 1536w, http://voicesofthechurch.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/pexels-pixabay-220067-2048x1152.jpg 2048w" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px"></figure>



<p>Paragraph 1</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I can’t figure out why its not styling correctly, but maybe someone can help…

If you need anything else, please let me know and I will provide further.  To view live, visit VoicesOfTheChurch.com.  It is the only thing on the page right now.

Answer (score 0):

Through the help of a friend, we were able to find the problem and came up with a solution.  WP was adding in a few other wp- tags that I never would have imagined would cause the problem.  I am posting this just in case it could be helpful for someone else running into this same issue.  I want to continue working on the JavaScript to make it better; however, here it goes!

```
var WPclasses  = [
  "is-layout-constrained",
  "is-layout-flex",
  "is-layout-flow",
];  

$(".WP-removeDefaultClasses").removeClass (function (index, className) {
  return (className.match (/\bwp-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
}).removeClass(WPclasses);
```

This looks for all `wp-` tags that Wordpress adds in and removes them all, only in “containers” that you specify so that you can have wp- tags within sub elements like images and paragraphs and other blocks within your custom blocks.  Gives full control over the areas you want to control vs what you want Wordpress to control.  I had to add in a few custom tags which are classified within a `WPclasses` array.  Simple, but effective!